# Get updated JS file after bundling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I am creating an `ASP.Net MVC` application. I have added a bundle for `javascript` files as below.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/surveyJS").Include(
          "~/Content/javascript/jquery-3.0.0.js",
          "~/Content/javascript/questionaire.js"));
```

I have updated `questionaire.js` and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd> but browser doesn't download new file.

I have also added `?v=1` at the end of file name to remove cache but it is not not downloading any file (not even older one).

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/surveyJS").Include(
          "~/Content/javascript/jquery-3.0.0.js",
          "~/Content/javascript/questionaire.js?v=1"));
```

I have also tried calling that bundle with `?v=1`

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/surveyJS?v=1")
```

but again, it does not download any file.

Please provide solution that I can use in production as well (means no rebuilding project or changing config solutions).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on a windows server you can try to reset the IIS or clear the server cache.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/delete-cached-objects

Comment: My project will have many js and css files and I don't want client's browser to load all of them if I change 1. I already mentioned that in my question.

Comment: All your question said was it can't rebuild or change the configs, nothing about downloading other JS or CSS. But it doesn't matter, you can delete a single object from Cache using Application Request Routing (ARR), as stated in the link from the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/delete-cached-objects

Comment: I can't find ARR under my IIS, I even downloaded and installed one.